# Flutter-How to use logical AND in firebase query and how to update data?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am new to flutter and looking for some sort of multiple where clauses or logical AND operator in my query, tried several things but none working for me. I am filtering users whose IDs match currently logged in user ID. Secondly there is a **bool** field **status** in firestore, I want to filter "status"==false as well. i.e

> where userid=="currently logged in userid" && status==false

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getData() async*{
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance.collection('order').where("userid", isEqualTo: firebaseUser.email.toString()).snapshots();
  }
```

Secondly, I want to update this approve = false to approve = true on button press how can I do that? My IDE is showing a red line below that.

```
onPressed: () async {
       await db.collection('booking_tbl').document(doc.documentID).updateData('approve':true);
  },
```

Full piece of code is here:

```
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: db.collection('booking_tbl').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Column(
            children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) {
              return ListTile(
                    title: Text("Press the button to confirm booking"),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await db.collection('booking_tbl').document(doc.documentID).updateData('approve':true);
                      },
                    ),
                ),
            }).toList(),
          );
        } else {
          return SizedBox();
        }
      }),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preform and query, you have to do the following:

```
yield* Firestore.instance.collection('order').where("userid", isEqualTo: firebaseUser.email.toString()).where("status", isEqualTo: false).snapshots();
```

This will perform and query, meaning if a document contains this userid `AND` status is false then you will retrieve that document.

---

Regarding the error here:

```
onPressed: () async {
       await db.collection('booking_tbl').document(doc.documentID).updateData('approve':true);
  },
```

`updateData()` takes a map as an argument, so do the following:

```
onPressed: () async {
       await db.collection('booking_tbl').document(doc.documentID).updateData({'approve':true});
  },
```

Comment: thanks my second error is resolved but first one still persists what alternatively I can do for it?

Comment: There is no error however its not filtering the results

Comment: Are u sure the userId is equal to the user email?

Comment: It should be firebaseUser.uid instead

Answer (score 1):

You just stack the where clausel:

```dart
final QuerySnapshot snap = await Firestore.instance.collection("order")
    .where("userid", isEqualTo: "id")
    .where("status", isEqualTo: false)
    .where("email", isEqualTo: "email")
    .where("number", isGreaterThan: 3)
    .getDocuments();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = snap.documents;
```

As stream:

```dart
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getData() async{
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return Firestore.instance.collection("order")
        .where("userid", isEqualTo: "id")
        .where("status", isEqualTo: false)
        .where("email", isEqualTo: "email")
        .where("number", isGreaterThan: 3)
        .snapshots();
}
```

Just be aware, that this does only take the **currently** logged in user, this will not update, when the user logs out and a new user logs in. The difference to your approach is, that i just map the streams, instead of specifying explicitly which elements to `yield` (and because i only map, the method does not need to be marked `async*`, only `async`, because i still have to `await` the call to get the currently logged in user).

The second question, should be in another question, but you need to give a Map as a parameter (wrap it in `{}`):

```dart
await db.collection('booking_tbl').document(doc.documentID).updateData({"approve":true});
```

Comment: My second error is resolved but first one still persists what alternatively I can do for it?

Comment: i think your stream mapping is a bit odd, edited answer